# Google Maps showing wrong location on mobile site

Tags: iphone, location, maps

We use google maps on our website to help visitors find our company better.
On iPhone ... Google Maps centers to a land section in the Czech Republic. Our company is located in Munich, distance 300 km southwest of the Google marked land section.
Everything is alright on PC Chrome Dev-Tools mobile view, as well as on Android devices.

All browsers on iPhones show an incorrect location. iPad not tested yet. What can the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

check the accuracy on google map API and note that iPhones get location through Internet (if you connect wifi or something then it can cause the problem). so use physical sensor on the phone. those config can found in it on google API Docs

[Google geo Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro)

use cellTowers only if GPS unavailable (if needed).

Comment: Oh, I would like to add: The position needle is set correctly on our company in Munich, but Maps focuses on a location in the Czech Republic. My colleague has just checked her iPhone, everything works fine with her (at both, cellular and Wifi). Just not on mine (at both, cellular and Wifi)! Is it really an API problem?